# committing semispace failed. allocation failed - process out of memory in meteor js ec2 instance

Tags: meteor, memory-management, amazon-ec2

I'm currently running a basic website on an amazon EC2 t1.micro instance.

The application is built using meteor js.

After a while I get the following error in the errors log file and the server crashes:

```
FATAL ERROR: Committing semi space failed. Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

Could somebody help me with this issue?
Have I misconfigured something?

Comment: Its a node.js issue

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried increasing the allocated memory, e.g. running node with `--max-old-space-size=4096`?

Comment: my ec2 was crashing about half of the time i ran meteor. i think its doing better after running: export TOOL_NODE_FLAGS="--max-old-space-size=4096"